# I have problem with .htacess. Site keeps loading constantly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently i installed one script and enabled the mod_rewrite. Now when i load the site its just keep refreshing without loading. If i disable rewrite, it works fine.

.htacess content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Than you

Comment: What do you mean _"keep refreshing without loading"_? Use Firebug for Firefox ("Net" panel) or any similar tool and see the network activity. Also -- check your web server (Apache?) logs.

Comment: refreshing means its keep on loading but site never loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error in the syntax of `.htaccess` file. All requests will be redirected to index.php where the information about requested path should be available in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

As recommended in the comment by LazyOne, try to check the network activity to see what's happening. If that doesn't help, look for the error in the PHP script.

Another tool which could help you with investigating what's happening is [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) Firefox extension.

Comment: I installed same in localhost and found the problem. when i enable Override All in httpd.conf  it works fine. Is there any risk involved in enabling on my server.

Comment: There's no risk provided that nobody except you can change the .htaccess file. If you are worried about security, you can disable it server-wide and enable for a particular virtual host only.